Unit testing a class that uses encryption
I am working on a relatively young ASP.NET Zero project, in which I am trying to implement unit testing.
I make use of NUnit and SQLite, in  order to be able to integration test repositories, objectmappers and such fully. I work with Abp 5.14 and Entity Framework Core 3.1.
Now my problem arises when I try to test a class that has a property with the [Encrypted] annotation.
This calls on EncryptedConverter and KeyProvider. KeyProvider creates a new IocManager scope that resolves the IAppConfigurationAccessor. This causes an exception:
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException: 'No component for supporting the service My_App.Configuration.IAppConfigurationAccessor was found'
In My_AppTestBaseModule.cs an implementation is actually registered, but apparently not persisted when the new IocManager scope is created: Configuration.ReplaceService<IAppConfigurationAccessor, TestAppConfigurationAccessor>();.
What is the conventional way of making this work? I had assumed it would right out of the box. I can't be exceptional for testing classes that use encryption, can I?
My .Test project is still fully boilerplate when it comes to configuration, hence me not posting any of my code.
